# Passing var url using window location

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, input

trying to open search results in window (enter and click) it looks like the code is doing what I want it to do except accessing the actual search url any help is greatly appreciated.

the site is also on dev so you can see what I mean if you enter a search term.
http://staging.asla.org/2014awards/index.html

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('form[role="search"]').submit(function() {
        var url = "http://asla.org/awardssearch.html";
        url += "?s=" + $('#GoogleCSE').val();
        window.location = url;
      });
   });
 </script>

 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="search">
        <input id="GoogleCSE" type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" value="Search All Awards" name="Search All Awards" />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
      </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please don't use inline scripting. It's poor practice. Instead abstract your event handling with `onclick`, `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` depending on your cross compatibility requirements

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue is that your input doesn't still have the search term when you go back to the page?

Comment: @EliWhite when you type a search term and hit enter or click the results do dont index at the /awardssearch url. Instead the user is stuck on the current page. I've added the dev url up top so you can see the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `location` doesn't work beacuse the browser has already started to post the form. The browser will go to the page specified in the `action` attribute in the form, and as you don't have one, it will use the current page.

Use the `preventDefault` method to stop the posting of the form:

```
$('form[role="search"]').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: Wow I hate when its the little hiccups. Your suggestion worked wonderfully thanks so much for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue caused is because of the on focus and onblir event where you are trying to show a placeholder text,
Change your input text to

```
      <input id="GoogleCSE" type="text" placeholder="Search All Awards"/>
```

It should work.